# my ODE won't get solved

Tags: warning-messages

I press ENTER but nothing happens. Not even the {}. Nothing.

DSolve[{y'[x] == (-x*y[x] - 1)/(4*x^3*y[x] - 2*x^2) }, y[x], x]

Have I written anything wrong?

Comment: It works for me. What's the version of Mma?

Comment: Press shift+enter.

Comment: Shift+enter worked. Thanks. Can I see the steps of the solution somehow?

Comment: No,Mathematica can't do this. If you whant steps post question to: https://math.stackexchange.com. Well, you can have a preview of what it is integrating: `Block[{Integrate}, 
 DSolve[{y'[x] == (-x*y[x] - 1)/(4*x^3*y[x] - 2*x^2)}, y[x], 
   x] /. {Integrate -> Inactive[Integrate]}]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1):

> Can I see the steps of the solution somehow?

Here is step-by-step solution.  May be Wolfram-Alpha can show step by step for this.

solve $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-xy-1}{4x^{3}y-2x^{2}}$. Write as

$$
M\left(  x,y\right)  +N\left(  x,y\right)  \frac{dy}{dx}=0
$$

Where
\begin{align*}
M  & =\left(  xy+1\right)  \\
N  & =\left(  4x^{3}y-2x^{2}\right)
\end{align*}

$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=x,\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}=12x^{2}y-4x$.
Since $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\neq\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$, then
the ODE is not exact. Let try to find an integrating factor $\mu$.

$$
R=\frac{\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}}
{xM-yN}=\frac{\left(  12x^{2}y-4x\right)  -x}{x\left(  xy+1\right)  -y\left(
4x^{3}y-2x^{2}\right)  }=\frac{12xy-5}{-4\left(  xy\right)  ^{2}+3xy+1}
$$

Since $R$ is a function of $xy$ only, then we got lucky, and found integrating factor $\mu=e^{\int R\left(  t\right)  dt}$
where $t=xy$.

\begin{align*}
\mu & =e^{\int\frac{\left(  12t-5\right)  }{\left(  -4t^{2}+3t+1\right)  }
dt}\\
& =e^{-\frac{7}{5}\ln\left(  1-t\right)  -\frac{8}{5}\ln\left(  1+4t\right)
}\\
& =\left(  1+4t\right)  ^{\frac{-8}{5}}\left(  1-t\right)  ^{\frac{-7}{5}}\\
& =\frac{1}{\left(  1+4xy\right)  ^{\frac{8}{5}}\left(  1-xy\right)
^{\frac{7}{5}}}
\end{align*}

Multiplying the original ODE by $\mu$ gives

\begin{align*}
\mu M\left(  x,y\right)  +\mu N\left(  x,y\right)  \frac{dy}{dx}  & =0\\
\frac{xy+1}{\left(  1+4xy\right)  ^{\frac{8}{5}}\left(  1-xy\right)
^{\frac{7}{5}}}+\frac{4x^{3}y-2x^{2}}{\left(  1+4xy\right)  ^{\frac{8}{5}
}\left(  1-xy\right)  ^{\frac{7}{5}}}\frac{dy}{dx}  & =0\\
\bar{M}\left(  x,y\right)  +\bar{N}\left(  x,y\right)    & =\frac{dy}{dx}
\end{align*}

Where
\begin{align*}
\bar{M}\left(  x,y\right)    & =\frac{xy+1}{\left(  1+4xy\right)  ^{\frac
{8}{5}}\left(  1-xy\right)  ^{\frac{7}{5}}}\\
\bar{N}\left(  x,y\right)    & =\frac{4x^{3}y-2x^{2}}{\left(  1+4xy\right)
^{\frac{8}{5}}\left(  1-xy\right)  ^{\frac{7}{5}}}
\end{align*}

Checking now shows that $\frac{\partial\bar{M}}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial
\bar{N}}{\partial x}$, so the ODE is now exact. Hence it can now be solved. Let

\begin{align}
\frac{dU}{dx}  & =\bar{M}\left(  x,y\right)  \tag{1}\\
\frac{dU}{dy}  & =\bar{N}\left(  x,y\right)  \tag{2}
\end{align}

From (1)

\begin{align}
U  & =\int\bar{M}dx+f\left(  y\right)  \nonumber\\
& =\int\frac{xy+1}{\left(  1+4xy\right)  ^{\frac{8}{5}}\left(  1-xy\right)
^{\frac{7}{5}}}dx+f\left(  y\right)  \nonumber\\
& =\frac{x}{\left(  1-xy\right)  ^{\frac{2}{5}}\left(  1+4xy\right)
^{\frac{3}{5}}}+f\left(  y\right)  \tag{3}
\end{align}

From (2)

\begin{align*}
\frac{dU}{dy}  & =\frac{2x^{2}\left(  -1+2xy\right)  }{\left(  1+xy\right)
^{\frac{7}{5}}\left(  1+4xy\right)  ^{\frac{8}{5}}}\\
\frac{d}{dy}\left(  \frac{x}{\left(  1-xy\right)  ^{\frac{2}{5}}\left(
1+4xy\right)  ^{\frac{3}{5}}}+f\left(  y\right)  \right)    & =\frac
{2x^{2}\left(  -1+2xy\right)  }{\left(  1+xy\right)  ^{\frac{7}{5}}\left(
1+4xy\right)  ^{\frac{8}{5}}}\\
\frac{2x^{2}\left(  -1+2xy\right)  }{\left(  1-xy\right)  ^{\frac{7}{5}
}\left(  1+4xy\right)  ^{\frac{8}{5}}}+f^{\prime}\left(  y\right)    &
=\frac{2x^{2}\left(  -1+2xy\right)  }{\left(  1+xy\right)  ^{\frac{7}{5}
}\left(  1+4xy\right)  ^{\frac{8}{5}}}\\
f^{\prime}\left(  y\right)    & =\frac{\left(  4x^{3}y-2x^{2}\right)
}{\left(  1+4xy\right)  ^{\frac{8}{5}}\left(  1-xy\right)  ^{\frac{7}{5}}
}-\frac{2x^{2}\left(  -1+2xy\right)  }{\left(  1-xy\right)  ^{\frac{7}{5}
}\left(  1+4xy\right)  ^{\frac{8}{5}}}\\
& =0
\end{align*}

Hence $f\left(  y\right)  =C$ and from (3)

$$
U=\frac{x}{\left(  1-xy\right)  ^{\frac{2}{5}}\left(  1+4xy\right)  ^{\frac
{3}{5}}}+C
$$

But $U=c_{0}$ some constant. Hence combining constants to one, the implicit
solution for $y\left(  x\right)  $ is

$$
\frac{x}{\left(  1-xy\right)  ^{\frac{2}{5}}\left(  1+4xy\right)  ^{\frac
{3}{5}}}+C=0
$$

To show the above is the same as solution by Mathematica, just apply solve for it. (I think implicit solution is easier in this case)

```
  eq=x/((1-x y)^(2/5) (1+4 x y)^(3/5))+C[1]==0;
  Solve[eq, y]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare to

```
  DSolve[{y'[x] == (-x*y[x] - 1)/(4*x^3*y[x] - 2*x^2)}, y[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I also verified the hand solution in Maple, using its `odetest()` function

```
restart;
ode:=diff(y(x),x)=(-x*y(x)-1)/(4*x^3*y(x)-2*x^2):
mysol:=x/((1-x*y(x))^(2/5)*(1+4*x*y(x))^(3/5))+_C1=0:
odetest(mysol,ode);
(* 0 *)
```

zero from `odetest` means the solution satisfies the ODE.

Comment: great answer! thank you! I've never seen this integrating factor though...